# Bookmarklet to edit beginning of URL

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

I'm looking for a simple bookmarklet to take the current URL of my website and refresh it with a couple of changes. For example:

1. Take the page's url, for example: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Frola_93494_1198753808_(5720175186).jpg
2. Replace the beginning, for example:
   https://tools.wmflabs.org/croptool/?title=Frola_93494_1198753808_(5720175186).jpg
3. Load the page in a new tab.

I appreciate any help

Comment: `window.open("https://tools.wmflabs.org/croptool/?title=" + location.href.split(":").pop())`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! How would I make it refresh the page instead of opening in a new tab?

Comment: Nevermind, it's javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.location.href =("https%3A%2F%2Ftools.wmflabs.org%2Fcroptool%2F%3Ftitle%3D" %2B location.href.split("%3A").pop())%7D)() :)